# Why is it so common to initialize weights with a Guassian distribution divided by the square root of number of neurons in a layer?

Tags: neural-networks

I have seen in several jupyter notebooks people initializing the NN weights using:

```
np.random.randn(D, M) / np.sqrt(D)
```

Other times they just do:

```
np.random.randn(D, M)
```

What is the advantage of dividing the Gaussian distribution by the squared root of the number of neurons in the layer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they use the Xavier/Glorot's initialization method. You can read from [the original paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf):

> We initialized the biases to be 0 and the weights $W_{ij}$ at each layer with the following commonly used heuristic:
>
> $W_{ij} \sim U [ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}] $
>
> where $U[−a, a]$ is the uniform distribution in the interval $(−a, a)$ and $n$ is the size of the previous layer (the number of columns of $W$)

Some people use this as some reports said this initialization method lead to better result